# Multidimensional integration using Divergence Theorem

Tags: integration, calculus-of-variations, divergence-theorem

Considering the following integral

$$ \delta U = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} \sigma_{ij}\left( \delta \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \delta \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \right) \text{d}\Omega \tag{1}$$

According to the book (Mechanical Vibrations - Michel Géradin and
Daniel J. Rixen) that I'm reading, applying the Divergence Theorem on (1) yields

$$ \delta U = \int_{\Gamma} n_j \sigma_{ij} \delta u_i\ \text{d}\Gamma - \int_{\Omega}\left(\frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j}\delta u_i \right) \text{d}\Omega \tag{2} $$

I cannot get it by applying the Divergente Theorem, as the authors said in the book.

Does someone know how I get (2) by applying Divergence Theorem on (1)?

**NOTES**

- $\sigma_{ij}$ is a symmetric tensor;
- $\delta$ is the variation from Calculus of Variations;
- $\Gamma$ is the boundary surface of $\Omega$.

Comment: I don't see a question here...  What happens when you expand the form you are interested in according to definitions?

Comment: Perhaps this is standard notation I’m not familiar with, but I have no idea what half of your variables represent. What’s the relationship between W and u? What is n? The variation is applied to a functional - what functions are U, $\epsilon$ functionals of?

Comment: I don't see divergences anywhere. How could you apply the divergence theorem?
What is the book you are reading? What are your thoughts? What do you expect from people reading this post?

Comment: @abiessu I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: @Eric, I've updated my question. These terms are not important in the derivation, at least I think.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz, I've updated my question. I would like any advice to go from (1) to (2) by applying Divergence Theorem on (1). Could you help me?

Comment: Do those partial derivatives commute with $\delta$?

Comment: Since $\sigma$ is symmetric, the first expression is just
$$\int_\Omega \sigma_{ij}\, \delta\partial_j u_i\,d\Omega.$$
If $\delta$ commutes with $\partial_j$, by the product rule you have
$$\sigma_{ij}\,\delta\partial_j u_i = \partial_j(\sigma_{ij}\,\delta u_i)-\partial_j\sigma_{ij}\,\delta u_i.$$
Substitute in the integral above and you get something which looks closer to what you want. Does this help?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz, yes, it commutes. It really looks closer, but I still cannot see where Divergence Theorem comes. Could you develop it further? I would glad to up vote your answer!

Comment: Jack’s first term on the right side is the divergence of a thing. Integrating that by the Divergence Theorem gives the integral of the dot product of the normal ($n_j$) with the thing ($\sigma_{ij}\delta u_i$)over the boundary which is your first term.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz, one more question. How does the factor 1/2 vanishes?

Comment: @Eric, I think that I got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ProfessorP.CosmoKlunk
Separate the integral in the two summands and use the symmetry of $\sigma$.